# Translated taxonomy term in contextupal filter not validating

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, i18n-l10n

I have a translated taxonomy term:

[image: term]

And have a simple view:

[image: view]

With a contextual filter on the translated taxonomy term:

[image: term]

Which works in english:

[image: english]

But not in french:

[image: french]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the taxonomy vocabulary type from "Localize" to "Translate".